# AngularJS 1.6. component templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm using the ES6, Webpack and AngularJS component based architecture to try and make a starter boilerplate. I have my app directory and inside it there is an index.js where I export the app module:

```
import { AppComponent } from './ng/app.component.js';

export default angular
    .module('appModule',[])
    .component('app', AppComponent)
```

as well as two other directories `ng` for js files and `templates` for htmls.

Inside `app.component.js` I'm tring to include the .html file like so:

```
export const AppComponent = {
    templateUrl: '../templates/app.html',
    controller: class AppController {
        constructor() {
            this.title = "App Page";
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/templates/app.html 404 (Not Found)
```

But when I type the full path to the file `src/app/templates/app.html` or `template: require('../templates/app.html')` it works as expected.

Is there a way I can make the `templateUrl` work without having to type the full path of requiring it ?

Comment: Is `../templates/app.html` the relative path from the component's `.ts` file (not the main)?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat Yes.

Answer (score 0):

For access one page without read full path you need to create Routes.

AngularJs 1.x
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Angular 2 or higher
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a way to add the code by using a session constant for example 
`templateUrl: CONFIG.baseUrl +'/templates/app.html'`

I would try also 
`templateUrl: ../../templates/app.html'`